# Cross-Correlation between two images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How can I select a random point on one image, then find its corresponding point on another image using cross-correlation?

So basically I have image1, I want to select a point on it (automatically) then find its corresponding/similar point on image2.

Here are some example images:

Full image:

[image: full image]

Patch:

[image: patch]

Result of cross correlation:

[image: result of cross correlation]

Comment: If you cross-correlate two (similar) images, the peak should correspond to the relative offset of the two images.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [SIFT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sift) or [SURF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surf) or do you specifically want to use cross-correlation? How do the two images relate with respect to scale, rotation, lighting, angle of view, ...?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth 
yes have to be cross correlation, They have some overlap. I want to get 4 points if possible, and want them to be as seperated as possible. I have tried something like C_1 = normxcorr2(image1, image2); however C_1 changes size then you cant get the actual points on image1 and 2

Comment: @mbschenkel yes have to be cross correlation, They have some overlap.

Comment: So what's the issue with [xcorr2](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html)?

Comment: @mbschenkel I want to get the corresponding coordinates (points) on image1 and image2. I have tried something like C_1 = normxcorr2(image1, image2); however C_1 changes size (double the size) then you cant get the actual points on image1 and 2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, `xcorr2` can essentially be seen as analyzing all possible shifts in both positive and negative direction and giving a measure for how well they fit with each shift. Therefore for images of size `N x N` the result must have size `(2*N-1) x (2*N-1)`, where the correlation at index `[N, N]` would be maximal if the two images where equal or not shifted. If they were shifted by 10 pixels, the maximum correlation would be at `[N-10, N]` and so on. Therefore you will need to subtract `N` to get the absolute shift.

With your actual code it would probably be easier to help. But let's look at an example:

(A) We read an image and select two different sub-images with offsets da and db

```
Orig = imread('rice.png');
N = 200; range = 1:N;
da = [0 20];
db = [30 30];
A=Orig(da(1) + range, da(2) + range);
B=Orig(db(1) + range, db(2) + range);
```

(b) Calculate cross-correlation and find maximum

```
X = normxcorr2(A, B);
m = max(X(:));
[i,j] = find(X == m);
```

(C) Patch them together using recovered shift

```
R = zeros(2*N, 2*N);
R(N + range, N + range) = B;
R(i + range, j + range) = A;
```

(D) Illustrate things

```
figure
subplot(2,2,1), imagesc(A)
subplot(2,2,2), imagesc(B)
subplot(2,2,3), imagesc(X)
rectangle('Position', [j-1 i-1 2 2]), line([N j], [N i])
subplot(2,2,4), imagesc(R);
```

(E) Compare intentional shift with recovered shift

```
delta_orig = da - db
%--> [30 10]
delta_recovered = [i - N, j - N]
%--> [30 10]
```

As you see in (E) we get exactly the shift we intenionally introduced in (A).

[image: Result of xcorr2]

---

Or adjusted to your case:

```
full=rgb2gray(imread('a.jpg'));
template=rgb2gray(imread('b.jpg'));
S_full = size(full);
S_temp = size(template);

X=normxcorr2(template, full);
m=max(X(:));
[i,j]=find(X==m);

figure, colormap gray
subplot(2,2,1), title('full'), imagesc(full)
subplot(2,2,2), title('template'), imagesc(template), 
subplot(2,2,3), imagesc(X), rectangle('Position', [j-20 i-20 40 40])

R = zeros(S_temp);
shift_a = [0 0];
shift_b = [i j] - S_temp;
R((1:S_full(1))+shift_a(1), (1:S_full(2))+shift_a(2)) = full;
R((1:S_temp(1))+shift_b(1), (1:S_temp(2))+shift_b(2)) = template;
subplot(2,2,4), imagesc(R);
```

[image]

However, for this method to work properly the patch (`template`) and the full image should be scaled to the same resolution.

---

A more detailed example can also be found [here](http://www.mathworks.ch/products/demos/image/cross_correlation/imreg.html).

Comment: thanks


imgray = rgb2gray(image);
imgray2 = rgb2gray(image2);

template = imgray(200:600,540:end);

C_1 = normxcorr2(template, imgray);
C_2 = normxcorr2(template, imgray2);

[y1, x1] = find(C_1 == max(abs(C_1(:))));
[y2, x2] = find(C_2 == max(abs(C_2(:))));

so here i took the highest point of C_1 and C_2, but they are not actual points on image1 and image2, as you said i need to subtract, so i have subtracted the template size but still wont give me the right points?

Comment: Ok, so you are doing this for a total of 3 images with probably different sizes. But it should be possible to just look at two of them at once (`ìmgray` vs. `template` in your case). Maybe it would help to show us the exact images to understand the problem better. If you look at the output of `normxcorr2`, do you see a clear peak and if so where?

Comment: I dont know how to post images onto here, but yes I get a clear bright spot (peak), so I want to take the coordinate of this bright spot (peak) and plot it on the actual image (imgray in my case) the image is 1728by2300, and tempate 1250by955

Comment: Then the coordinates of that "spot" minus the size of `template` gives you the coordinates in `imgray` and vice versa. I'd recommend you to start with a known offset as in my answer, so you know what to expect.

You can upload images e.g. [here](http://imgur.com/) and link to them in your question. With more reputation you will also be able to upload directly.

Comment: yes I have done that, subtracted the template size, but somehow it didnt plot in the right place. here is the link for the images http://imgur.com/a/9M14y/all

Comment: I've added the images to your question and updated my answer.

Comment: thanks mate, I wanted that little square to be on the full image as well?